# How can I save the formkey?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

```
onPressed: () async {
    _emailTaken = false;
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      app.loading = true;
    });
    await isRegister(emailController.value.text);
    if (_emailTaken) {
        setState(() {
            app.loading = false;
        });
    _formKey.currentState.validate();
    return;
    }
}
```

Here's a passage to check if my user's email has already been register.

but I meet

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'validate' was called on null.

here's my emailTextForm's validator

```
validator: (String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) return '*1';
    if (!value.contains('@')) return '*2';
    if (_emailTaken) return '*3';
    return null;
}
```

and my isRegister() method

```
Future<void> isRegister(String email) async {
    await fireStore.collection('Users').doc(email).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      _emailTaken = ds.exists;
    });
  }
```

Here's the overall structure.

```
class _SignInWidgetState extends State<SignInWidget> {
  ...
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final app = AppState(false, null);
  ...

  isVerified(String email, String pass) async {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }

  Future<void> Login(String email,String pass) async{
    ...
  }

  Future<void> isRegister(String name) async {
    ...
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String pass) async {
    ...
  }

  Widget _logIn() {
    return GestureDetector(
      ...
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ...
                 SignInButtonBuilder(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    emails = 0;
                    passs = 0;
                    _isVerified = true;
                    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) return;
                    setState(() {
                      app.loading = true;
                    });
                    ...
                    setState(() {
                      app.loading = false;
                    });
                    _formKey.currentState.validate();
                  },
                ),
                ...
```

There's an error in the In the second "_formKey.currentState.validate()" part at the bottom.

The Error is Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'validate' was called on null.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please don't use the `android-studio` tag just because you're using it to develop your app. only use it if you're asking about a feature of the IDE

Comment: Oh ok, I got you.

Answer (score 0):

Where you define your formKey, you should also instantiate it like:

```
var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Have you done it?

Comment: Yes, I've declared it. However, when the app state changes and returns, the form remains intact, but the _formKey is initialized.

Comment: Could you provide some code about where do you initialize it?

Comment: I've corrected question. Can you help me?